# Make :after the same size as its element

Tags: html, css

I have a nav menu that has different size cells for each item. Under each item I want a triangle image to indicate the active menu item.
How can I make the `:after` reflect the same size as the parent so that I can have the content of the `:after` centered properly?

Code for the menu:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#solutions">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#business">Your Business</a></li>              
        <li><a href="#security">Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way here is use `absolute` position on the `:after` element and use the `li` or `a` tag parent as relative. Like this:

```
.nav > li a {
  position: relative;
}
.nav > li a:after {
  content: "\25B2";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

<kbd>**Check The Snippet**</kbd>

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.nav > li {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: orange;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}
.nav > li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'verdana';
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background .3s ease
}
.nav > li a:hover {
  background: red;
}
.nav > li a:after {
  content: "\25B2";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#solutions">Solutions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#business">Your Business</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#security">Security</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ooh ok. My problem is that I was putting the after on the li, not the a. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css, include text in the content: " " and set the color to transparent via rgba. then set background to an image

```
.nav-pills {
width: 100%;
display:block;
list-style:none;
}
.nav-pills li{
display:inline;
float:left;
margin: 0 20px;
padding:4px 10px
background:#d7d7d7;
text-align:center;
}
.nav-pills li::after { 
content: " Image";
padding: 4px 10px;
background:url(images/image.png);
background-color:orange;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
display:block;
}
```

Check out my codepen  [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByQqpw)

Comment: This is giving a fixed width to the li, which is what I don't want

Comment: Edited my answer, now scales off text via padding;